# In Windows 7, a process started with CreateProcessAsUser by a windows service with a local system account crashes

Tags: com, windows-services, 64-bit, createprocessasuser

In Windows 7, a process started with CreateProcessAsUser by a windows service with a local system account crashes, but the same process started manually runs fine. The CreateProcessAsUser functionality is in a separate COM component [64 bit C++ dll], and the windows service [dot net 4.6.1] has platform target [Any CPU]. The process does not write anything to the event log either, suggesting that no code is executed, and it crashes immediately. This code works perfectly in windows 10.

I tried to attach to the process but it ends too soon to do anything. I do get a message "Module not found" , suggesting that it doesnt find a library. But I cant figure out which one. I gave it all the libraries it needs, which can be seen by the fact that the program runs ok when started manually from the same folder. I also tried to specify the startup folder in the function CreateProcessAsUser, but there was no difference, but I think it starts in the correct folder by default [where it is located]
I found the following link on SO
[Why is this process crashing as soon as it is launched?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15581142/why-is-this-process-crashing-as-soon-as-it-is-launched)
But it did not help either. ProcMon does not show where a module was not found [It says PATH NOT FOUND if I remove a known module]

The process exit status is  -1066598274
and the stack trace is
0   ntoskrnl.exe    RtlNtStatusToDosError + 0x1086  0xfffff8000712f206  C:\Windows\system32\ntoskrnl.exe
1   ntoskrnl.exe    RtlCopySidAndAttributesArray + 0x1789   0xfffff8000714b0d9  C:\Windows\system32\ntoskrnl.exe
2   ntoskrnl.exe    RtlNtStatusToDosError + 0x1538  0xfffff8000712f6b8  C:\Windows\system32\ntoskrnl.exe
3   ntoskrnl.exe    KeSynchronizeExecution + 0x3a23 0xfffff80006e75e53  C:\Windows\system32\ntoskrnl.exe

The event viewer shows the following information
Faulting application name: BizBrainAgentPluginHost.exe, version: 1.0.0.0, time stamp: 0x5b88084d
Faulting module name: KERNELBASE.dll, version: 6.1.7601.18015, time stamp: 0x50b8479b
Exception code: 0xc06d007e
Fault offset: 0x0000000000009e5d
Faulting process id: 0x484
Faulting application start time: 0x01d440746491e037
Faulting application path: C:\Program Files\Avinashi Ventures Pvt Ltd\myTallyApp Agent\BizBrainAgentPluginHost.exe
Faulting module path: C:\Windows\system32\KERNELBASE.dll
Report Id: a2f39c97-ac67-11e8-94f1-0023ae9747d0

Thanks

Comment: The same process runs ok when the platform target is x86

Comment: I removed all dependencies other than the default dot net ones, but the problem still persists. This seems to point to an issue with the 64bit dot net framework